# how to get logging working for EMR on EKS (i.e. emr-containers)

Tags: amazon-emr, amazon-eks

I am trying to get logging working with EMR on EKS (a.k.a. emr-containers).

I am using this configuration:

```json
    "monitoringConfiguration": {
      "cloudWatchMonitoringConfiguration": {
        "logGroupName": "/emr-containers/jobs", 
        "logStreamNamePrefix": "demo"
      }, 
      "s3MonitoringConfiguration": {
        "logUri": "s3://my-bucket/my-prefix"
      }
```

And my execution role is correct:

```
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        Effect: "Allow",
        Action: [
          "s3:PutObject",
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        Resource: "*"
      },
      {
        Effect: "Allow",
        Action: [
          "logs:PutLogEvents",
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
          "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
        ],
        Resource: [
          "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
```

However, when I look at cloudwatch, there is nothing in this log group, and similarly when I look at S3, there is nothing there.

It doesn't matter whether the job succeeds or fails -- in all cases there are no logs persisted either to cloudwatch or s3.

Any suggestions?

Comment: when my emr+eks jobs succeed, the logs are available. however, only when a given job fails, the aws console ui just shows a `Unable to launch application UI` after pressing the icon (and buffering for a few seconds). a link is provided to here and doesn't really help much: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/emr-eks-jobs-console.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you check the logs of the fluentd side car container that runs in the job-runner, driver and executor pods? This would be a good starting point.

Your job execution role has the proper policy for S3 and Cloudwatch, so make sure you [update the trust policy of the execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/setting-up-trust-policy.html) so that the EKS cluster can assume the role.

Lastly you should confirm that you completed the step to [enable IRSA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/setting-up-enable-IAM.html) for the EKS cluster.

Comment: updating the trust policy did it (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/setting-up-trust-policy.html) -- thanks!

Comment: I am unable to run  aws emr-containers update-role-trust-policy --cluster-name my-cluster --namespace kube-system --role-name EMREKSROLE --region us-east-2

it gives me the following error, Am I missing something?
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are: